# Android- screen brightness diminishes on launch

Tags: android, webview, screen-brightness

I am developing an android app in which i am just opening a website in a webview.

Everything was working fine, but suddenly i noticed that when i launch my app, phone's screen brightness diminishes automatically to a slightly low than normal. But when i tap on the screen it regains the normal brightness.

Below is the code of the my app.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /**********To hide the notification bar & letting the app to cover fullscreen********/
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        /************************************************************************************/

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /******To hide Actionbar ie the top black strip showing the activityName*******/
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        /************************************************************************************/

        w= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        /*********Getting the webView settings object and make the required changes**********/
        WebSettings setting = w.getSettings();
        setting.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        setting.setSupportZoom(false);
        setting.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        /************************************************************************************/

        /**********Enabling JavaScript*************/
        w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        /***********************************************************************************/

        /***********Create an interface to call android methods from javascript*************/
        w.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
        /***********************************************************************************/

        /*********Enabling the sound on in the webView***********/
        w.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
        /***********************************************************************************/

        try{
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            latitute = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(WelcomeActivity.app_files_dir_name, "Location couldn't be accessed!" + e.getMessage());
        }

        w.loadUrl(url);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xyz.abc.lmn.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/web_view">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loadingSpinner"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.abc.lmn" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_update_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Downloads"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_downloads" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am unable to find the resolution of this issue i am facing. Please can you suggest me one?

Comment: Nothing bad with your code. Check your device's display settings. You had set it to Auto i guess.

Comment: @NomanHamid thanks for the reply, I have tested this on many devices, but got the same result. Auto brightness display setting change also gives the same result. 
:(

Comment: How is the Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have added the **AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering own question as I resolved it myself.
Actually the problem was, I was calling a method to check if there is an network connection available before everything.
If internet connection is not available I open a **dialogBox** saying "No Internet Connection!".

But due to some reason dialog box was unable to open/display which results the screen brightness diminish. I removed that code and problem solved.

Thanks to all for valuable comments.